# Capture text inside start/end character but ignore doubled end character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the text inside my start/end characters ("<" ">") with Regex, while ignoring a doubled end character inside the text (so "<<" should be included in the captured data).

I tried

```
<([^>]*)>
```

and

```
<(.*?)>(?!>)
```

But am currently failing in following case:

Input:

```
<test>>Value>
```

Expected Output:

```
test>>Value
```

But my Regex capture only part of the strings.

The first one captures

```
test
```

and the second

```
test>
```

Sadly i am out of ideas on how to further approach the problem.
Does one of you Regex gods have any ideas how to solve this?

Edit:

Thanks for the Answers, sadly they do not match another requirement i have (which i dropped to keep the question as short as possible thinking it wouldnt matter... Lesson learned)

Input:

```
<test>>Value><test>
```

Expected Output:

```
test>>Value
test
```

Comment: What is wrong with the first example you give... it appears to work for me.

Comment: @RickRunowski ah i forgot that this one did output "test" and not "test>". Its still wrong, but i will clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [zero-width negative lookahead assertion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion) to match a `>` not followed by another `>` to terminate the match seems the simplest way:

```
<(.*)>(?!>)
```

captures `test>>more` when matched against `<test>>more>`.

Note, your second regex (`<(.*?)>(?!>)`) is using the minimal matching modifier, so will stop at the *first* `>` not followed by another `>`.

**EDIT**:

With the additional information, so `<test>>more><another>` should capture `test>>more` and `another`:

```
 <([^>]*(?:>>[^>]*)*)>
```

using `Regex.Matches` will make the above captures.

Expanded

```
 <       # Match <
 (       # Start capture
  [^>]*  #  Match many non->
  (?:    #  Start non-capturing group
   >>    #   Match >>
   [^>]* #   Match many non->
  )*     #   Repeat zero or more
 )       #  End capture
 >       # Match >
```

Ie. it breaks up the content of the angle brackets into `>>` and non-`>` blocks and matches an indefinite number of them. It will handle `<>>>` (captures `>>`).

Comment: That's better than my option: `<((.*[>]{2,}.*)|[^>]*)>`

Comment: This matches `test>>more> or even more` in `<test>>more> or even more>` which I guess is wrong. See it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gL1jX2/1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation, i really wondered why that second one didnt work. Your Answer matches the original Question but does not work with another Requirement which i left out for the sake of a short, minimal question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my go at it :)

```
<((?:>>|[^>])*)>
```

It starts by matching the opening `<` and then tries to match `>>`, and if not matched, any character other than `>`, repeated until the ending `>` is found,

It also works with the added requirements ;)

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xK5xT4/1).

Comment: This is good, I also played with this variant: [`<((?>>>|[^>]+)*)>`](https://regex101.com/r/wZ3uF8/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use : and get group 1st

```
(?:\<)(.*)(?:\>)
```

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/hU4vO7/7)

Answer (score -1):

```
(\w+)>{1,2}(\w+)
```

Or try this, without `<` at the beginning and `>` at the end.

Comment: I'm guessing, but I'm pretty sure it still should match `<test>`

Comment: Correct guess ClasG, clarified the Question.

Comment: Could someone explain me, why in this expression <(.*)>(?!>) what quesiton mark before ! and > does?